# Credentials don't pass

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, credentials

The program work well on my computer and on two others but for the fourth I got a COM-Exception 0x800x000e...

I have identified the problem. It is a webBrowser who doesn't want to navigate to the URL due to credentials...

The code:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://user:pass@IP:Port/so=" + textBox1.Text);
```

If I try to pass:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://IP:Port/so=" + textBox1.Text);
```

It works and ask the credentials after that. I try to pass this too:

```
string user = "user";
string pass = "pass";
string auth = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user + ":" + pass)) + "\r\n";
webBrowser1.Navigate("IP:Port/so=" + textBox1.Text, null, null, auth);
```

but the same error occurs :/

Comment: So are you asking how to pass the credentials programmatically?

Comment: Title is used to describe the problem, you can paste the exception at post body.

Comment: The credentials pass (programmatically) on 3 computers but on the fourth they don't pass.